# How to check android permission promise is successful or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, promise

In my RN application, I have the following code.

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

export default new Promise(() => {
   return PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS, {
        title: 'Contacts List',
        message: 'Canvas would like to view your contacts',
   });
});
```

What I want to do is, I want to return, if the promise is successful or not. Then, I can get the promised status and handle the android permissions according to that. But the current code returns this.

```
40
:
0
_55
:
null
_65
:
0
_72
:
null
__proto__
:
Object
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the function for the current authority is asynchronous, if the result is returned immediately, the value is returned before the result is obtained. Therefore, it is advisable to check the value after putting it in the variable. Or, it is desirable to receive the results after conversion in a synchronous fashion.

That **`object`** at the end looks like the value you want.

**example (Use Async )**

```js
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';

async function requestCameraPermission() {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
        message:
          'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
          'so you can take awesome pictures.',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log('You can use the camera');
    } else {
      console.log('Camera permission denied');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
}
```

**example (Use Sync )**

```js
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';

 function requestCameraPermission() {
  try {
     PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
        message:
          'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
          'so you can take awesome pictures.',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    ).then(result =>  { console.log(result) }).catch(err => console.log(err));

  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const requestPermission = async (requestedType) => {
  try {
    return await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(requestedType);
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
};

 const permissionsRequired = [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION];
 const permissionResponse = yield call(requestPermission, permissionsRequired);
```

Try above code. Hope this help.